# ImageList pictures not showing up in ImageIndex or ImageKey

Tags: vb.net

I've encountered an annoying problem while creating a new application today.

I was trying to add an image to a `TabControl` in Windows Forms (vb.net) using an `ImageList` but for some reason they no longer show up in the `ImageIndex` or `ImageKey` properties of controls. It keeps showing (none) only.

Never had this before and haven't done anything unusual.

Anyone else had this problem?
Can't find anything on the web.

I'm using Visual Studio 2015.

[image]

Comment: did you assign an imagelist to the tabcontrol?

Comment: @Plutonix Oh wow, completely forgot about this part since I haven't used it in a while. I feel dumb now. Thanks!